# My form submission get blocked because the frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set

Tags: javascript, hubspot

I'm trying to build a custom form and submission post for Hubspot.

I have the following code

**HTML**

```
<head>
<script src="prezzi-form-submit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <form class='form-inline' id='my-custom-form'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type='email' class='form-control' placeholder='Your email address' required>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type='submit'>Sign up</button>
  </form>

  <!-- Actual form that gets submitted to HubSpot -->
  <div class="hidden" id='hubspot-form'>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/current.js"></script>
    <script>
      hbspt.forms.create({
        portalId: 'my-portal-id',
        formId: '92b9b82a-0da2-4e23-8a30-04541c05ce6d',
        onFormReady: function($form) {
          $form.attr('target', 'hubspot-iframe');
        }
      });
    </script>

    <!-- iFrame that data will get submitted to. This hack stops the page redirect. -->
    <iframe name="hubspot-iframe" id="hubspot-iframe" sandbox="allow-forms"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS (prezzi-form-submit.js)**

```
// // Send form data to HubSpot from the client.
function submitToHubSpot(data) {
  var $form = $('#hubspot-form form'),
      k;

  // Loop through each value and find a matching input.
  // NOTE: Doesn't support checkbox/radio.
  for (k in data) {
    $form.find("input[name='" + k + "']").val(data[k]);
  }

  $("form input:submit").trigger("click");
}

// Here's how you'd use this.
$('#my-custom-form').on('submit', function() {
  var formData = {};
  $(this).serializeArray().forEach(function(data) {
    formData[data.name] = data.value;
  });

  submitToHubSpot(formData);

  // We sent the data. Now do whatever else you want.
  alert('Gee, thanks Jonathan! Now I can focus on onboarding my customers with Appcues!');
  window.location.href = 'http://appcues.com';
})
```

When I press the submit button, I get the following error in the console

> Blocked form submission to " " because the form's frame is sandboxed
>   and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

As you can see I have the

> sandbox="allow-forms"

set in the I frame but it isn't working.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: There are not enough elements to give a certain solution but it seems to me there is a bad response from the server. Probably Javascript is making a preflight call in HTTP OPTIONS method to see if it can really call the form action but the server is responding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that doesn't let the form submit. I'd suggest you check the network tab in your browser and have a look at the requests being sent to the server and relative responses.

Comment: I have been seeing similar behavior (not in Hubspot but in other applications we are running locally).  I'm not sure if this is a change to browsers as it happened without and source code changes.  The weird thing is it is happening on Chrome, Edge & Firefox.

Answer (score 56):

Sometimes when you click a link from an application, the tab opened will have javascript disabled/sandboxed.

Close the tab and reopen the same URL in a fresh tab, it might work.

Comment: hmm, not bad.. Thanks!

Comment: Weirdly, that worked. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me on duluth trading checkout lol

Comment: Worked on Linkedin!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem with an iFrame form on Hubspot and got the same JS error. Discovered it has to do with the live preview using the HS Design tool.

In the drop down at the top there's the "Live preview with display options" then the "Preview without display options". It's the "preview with display options" selection that makes it "Sandboxed", try the one without. Hope this is helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the allow-form attribute in the html, set it within the .js using

```
el.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-forms');
```

It is because the frame itself is being sandboxed but the script is being called prior to the form being submitted which triggers submission of the frame but since the user wouldn't be able to submit, it wont call the iframe properties to respect the attribute set there